# PagesController CakePHP executa apenas a action display

Tags: php, cakephp-2

Criei o `home.ctp` na pasta `/Views/Page/`, e ele está funcionando, também criei o método home, porém, ao acessar `/pages/home/`, o único método acessado é o display, alguém sabe dizer o por que?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oque estava ocorrendo e que no arquivo de configuração Routes estava forçando qualquer chamada ao controller Pages chamar a action dispay e passar o nome da pagina como parâmetro.